# How to count toggled buttons in jqueryui after a click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to count how many buttons are toggled using the [jqueryui checkbox button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox) option - .buttonset(). This needs to happen when a button is toggled.

I added a unique class to the labels before applying the button set and have set a click event on it.

It fires fine, however it is firing before the jqueryui has processed the click so the result is out of date. How do I apply the click event after jqueryui has done its job?

```
$(".button-set").click(function(){
    var selected = $("#offer_list_4 label[aria-pressed=true]").length; // out of date
});
```

Comment: Any chance of some more detailed markup, a better explanation of what the user sees on screen and what you expect to happen when each element is clicked on?

Comment: I'd have to write up a demo as the real code is more complex.  However the problem is not a bug, but conceptual. jqueryui buttons do not have public click events, so I don't know how to add my own click event handler that will be certain to fire after the jqueryui one.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve this is to bind an event handler to the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the inputs themselves (this is still triggered even though jQueryUI is doing some trickery with the labels).  For example:

```
$("#offer_list_4 input:checkbox").bind("change", function() {
    var selected = $("#format > input:checkbox:checked").length;
});
```

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/TGR68/

Takes advantage of the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and the [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).